# Expression for $E[|X - E[X]|^3]$

Tags: probability-theory

I've read in some lecture notes that, for $X$ being a Bernoulli(p) random variable it follows that
$$
E[|X - E[X]|^3]  = p (1-p)^3 + (1-p)p^3.
$$
However, I don't see how to derive this result from the left side. If it wasn't for the modulus, I could simply expand the expression and then use linearity of expectation. But how do I deal with the modulus here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E[X] = p$, so $E[|X - E[X]|^3] = E[|X - p|^3]$. $X = 1$ with probability $p$ and $X = 0$ with probability $1 - p$, so you get that

$$
E[|X - E[X]|^3] = E[|X - p|^3] = p\cdot|1 - p|^3 + (1 - p) \cdot |0 - p|^3 = p(1 - p)^3 + (1 - p)p^3.
$$